# make up for (me) not having been sticking by her side

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

How could I change the following sentence to make it sound better?

It would be a great opportunity to make up for (me) not having been sticking by her side when she came down with the flu.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a great opportunity to make up for my absence when she was sick with the flu.